# Grant Ownership to a USER

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, privileges, ownership

We want to replace our Ownership to SECURITYADMIN from one user to another

1. Is it possible to transfer privileges between users or clone user privileges?
2. How do we add Privileges and take Ownership on it?

Comment: Why would you grant ownership to users rather than roles? The access control is usually done based on roles as explained [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html). To grant ownership to a role you can use the command [GRANT OWNERSHIP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html).

Comment: You are correct, We will only grant ownership to the Role and users to roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Snowflake applies "Role-based Access Control (RBAC)". Therefore you should not consider granting privileges directly to users. It's not possible. All privileges are assigned to roles, and those roles are assigned to users.

You mentioned SECURITYADMIN. It is a pre-defined role that is not owned by any other role. Why do you want to change the ownership of it? If you want to assign SECURITYADMIN from one user to another, you just need to run these commands:

```
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
GRANT ROLE SECURITYADMIN TO USER NEW_USER;
REVOKE ROLE SECURITYADMIN FROM USER OLD_USER;
```

1. Is it possible to transfer privileges between users or clone user privileges?

As you will assign privileges to roles, you can just grant the role to another user, so they will have the same privileges.

2. How do we add Privileges and take Ownership on it?

You can use GRANT command to add privileges:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html

You can use GRANT OWNERSHIP to transfer the ownership:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Grant Ownership command is an option to achieve this requirement: [https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html#:~:text=Transfers%20ownership%20of%20an%20object,see%20Access%20Control%20in%20Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html#:%7E:text=Transfers%20ownership%20of%20an%20object,see%20Access%20Control%20in%20Snowflake).
2. To add privileges, use the "Grant" command on the specific objects and assign to specific roles.
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html